# How to pass arguments when debugging a dot net application

Tags: .net, console

I have an command line that uses arguments, I have no problem with this, but each time I want to test the application, I need to compile it, run the CMD, call the application with the parameters from the CMD, because I didn't find any solution that let me dynamically pass arguments to the console in Visual Studio
Any idea about that?
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Goto `Project->Properties` and click the `Debug` Tab.

There is a section for command line arguments:

[image]

Comment: @Wolfgang Jacques: I'm using VS 2019 and it's still called "Command Line Arguments" for a console application.

Comment: My bad @Mitch Wheat I was looking at my .NET CORE Application.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using VS 2022, go to the project properties -> Debug -> General, and then click on "Open debug launch profiles UI".

Comment: It's incredible that a 13 years old question still get new and relevant answers.

Answer (score 5):

Right click your project in VS -> Properties -> Debug tab

There is an area where you can specify command line arguments.  When you debug your project, VS will start it up with these args.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the project properties - Debug section, and under the Start Options heading there is a section for Command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It is called 'Application arguments' now
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for those who are using Visual Studio for Mac (tested on 17.3 preview). Navigate this via a top dropdown menu:

Project -> {your project name} Properties -> Run -> Configurations -> Default -> Arguments:

and enter arguments in this field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This information used to be persisted in a `ProjectName.csproj.user` file.
In the new `.csproj` format, this information is persisted in `Properties\launchsettings.json`. My current version of Visual Studio (17.3.2 apparently reads **both** of those when debugging.

If you ever see unexpected arguments, this may be the cause.

[More detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73500025/3968276).

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is using VS Code for their project, you guys can just open the `launch.json` in the `.vscode` folder and under `configurations` you can just add an `args` key value pair like this:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "args": ["What command you use to list all docker images"],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "stopAtEntry": false
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it can be more convenient to specify the arguments in Program.cs:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
#if DEBUG
    args = ["arg1", "arg2"]; // (C# 12 collection expression)
#endif
    ...
}
```