# Debug command line arguments appearing out of nowhere after upgrade from .NET Framework to .NET 6

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, csproj

I upgraded a project from .NET Framework 4.7.2 to .NET 6. When I ran the program in the Visual Studio debugger, an unexpected argument (call it `foo`) was passed to `Program.Main`.

Where did `foo` come from? The project properties' **Debug** page shows no arguments:

[image: Application arguments (empty)]

Nothing to see here, in other words. Then I added a `bar` argument:

[image: Application arguments (with 'bar')]

`Program.Main` now got passed an array of **two** strings, `foo` and `bar`. What's happening?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The upgrade part turns out to be central here. Most likely, just switching to the modern `.csproj` format is enough to trigger this weirdness.

Visual Studio now keeps things like application arguments in `Properties\launchSettings.json`, e.g.:

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "MyProgram": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

Before the upgrade, that information lived in `MyProject.csproj.user`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <StartArguments>foo</StartArguments>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Visual Studio apparently reads **both** files when starting debugging; it's not clear whether this is intentional or just a bug. (It would've made sense if the [.NET Upgrade Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview) had simply moved that information, from old place to new.

#### Solution

I deleted the `.csproj.user` file, though removing the `StartArguments` tag will surely work too. Don't forget to restart Visual Studio!

Comment: In 17.7 we've added a warning to the launch profile editor to highlight when a `StartArguments` value exists. https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/pull/9074. Hopefully that will help avoid this confusion.